# Constructor can't make object from abstract class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm programming a chessboard, and I've a base class chesspiece (schaakstuk in my language) and all the pieces like king, queen, are derived from that base class.

Now I wanted to create an object and fill a array with objects to start the game. Visual studio is giving me some errors on this line:

```
bord[1][kolom] = new Schaakstuk(Schaakstuk::WIT);
bord[6][kolom] = new Pion(Schaakstuk::ZWART);
```

that it is impossible to create from a abstract class. I don't see the error, first I thought it was that I was using a pure virutal function in my derived class but that isn't it, I'm only using a pure virtual function in my base class.

Constructor

```
for( int kolom = 0; kolom < SIZE; kolom++ )
{
    bord[1][kolom] = new Pion(Schaakstuk::WIT);
    bord[6][kolom] = new Pion(Schaakstuk::ZWART);
}
```

Pion.h

```
#include "Schaakstuk.h"
#include "Exceptions.h"

#ifndef PION
#define PION

class Pion: public Schaakstuk
{
public:
    Pion(void);
    ~Pion(void);
    bool ZetIsLegaal( int rij1, int kolom1, int rij2, int kolom2 ) const;
    void PrintStuk( void ) const;
    void GeefCor( int tabel [8][2], int rij, int kolom, int rij1, int kolom1) const;
    bool IsPion( void ) const { return true; };

private:
    bool ControleerZet( int rij1, int kolom1, int rij2, int kolom2 ) const;
};

#endif
```

Schaakstuk.h

```
#ifndef SCHAAKSTUK
#define SCHAAKSTUK
static const int SIZE1 = 8;

class Schaakstuk
{
public:
    enum kleurType { WIT, ZWART };
    Schaakstuk(kleurType kleur = WIT)
    {
        this->kleur = kleur;
    };
    virtual bool ZetIsLegaal( int rij1, int kolom1, int rij2, int kolom2 ) = 0;
    virtual void PrintStuk( void ) = 0;
    virtual void GeefCor( int tabel [8][2], int rij, int kolom, int rij1, int kolom1) = 0;
    kleurType GeefKleur( void ) const { return kleur; };
    virtual bool IsPion( void ) = 0;

protected:
    bool static NietOutOfBounds( int rij, int kolom );

private:
    kleurType kleur;
};
#endif
```

is my dropbox with the code files. Can someone help me?

this are the errors:

http://pastebin.com/82j08rry

and here is the full code

http://ideone.com/sWjxS

Comment: I'm sure as hell not downloading a RAR file from some unknown user's Dropbox.

Comment: Post a testcase to ideone.com.

Comment: Please put your class declarations in your question, but judging from your errors, you have pure virtual functions in `Pion`, and if that's true, you can not create a new instance of `Pion` directly, only one of its subclasses that implements all the pure virtuals and isn't abstract.

Comment: Best thing about coming up with a test case is that along the way you are likely to find the error yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If the error is along the lines of "Can't instantiate abstract class" then the next line should tell you which method is abstract.

Most likely is you have declared a pure virtual in the base class but didn't override it (or override it properly; see below) in the derived class.

First check to make sure you have an override in `Schaakstuk` and `Pion`, and then check to make sure you haven't changed the signature at all.  This could be a different const/volatile qualification, or different method parameters.

Comment: Based on your error message, this is the problem. You must implement all your pure virtual functions in the child class, and the signatures must match exactly.

Comment: Thanks found the error. const = 0 was needed ;-) Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

The word 'abstract' is the give away. You need to create from a concrete class - i.e. the compiler needs to know everything about the ins and outs of that object.

Comment: John it only contains .cpp .h files.